# angularjs sortable - update sort order property

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am creating an angularjs app that also uses jquery ui sortable. I'm looking for a clean way to update a "SortOrder" property on my models based on their position on the page, every time a sort is performed.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<div class="object-container" sortable>
    <div ng-repeat="object in objects">
        <div class="obj-title">{{object.Title}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my sortable directive:

```
myApp.directive('sortable', function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function(scope, element, attributes){
            element.sortable({
                helper : 'clone',
                stop : function(event, ui){
                    scope.syncOrder();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And my "syncOrder" function:

```
$scope.syncOrder = function(){
    // some speculation here:
    for(var i in $scope.objects){
        $scope.objects[i].SortOrder = ???;
    }
};
```

The SortOrder property exists and is set on page load, but obviously they need to be updated upon sorting, so I can pass the updated set back to the server and save. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you have a look at [ui-sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, we need a way to tie the elements to the objects in our model. We can do this by giving our elements in the repeater an ID and grabbing that ID when the sort stops.

```
<ul sortable>
    <li id="elem-{{obj.id}}" ng-repeat="obj in objects">
        { obj.message }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now in our directive we need to use the sortable's `toArray` method ([documentation here](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray)) to get a list of all element IDs and their positions and we need to pass that into our `syncOrder` function.

```
app.directive('sortable', function ($timeout) {
  return function (scope, element, attributes) {
    element.sortable({
        stop: function(event, ui){
            scope.syncOrder(element.sortable('toArray'));
        }
    });
  };
});
```

Now we can modify our `syncOrder` function to iterate over all objects in our model, then iterate over all elements in the array passed in by sortable, compare the IDs, and update the model to reflect the new positions.

```
$scope.syncOrder = function (elemPositions) {
    // loop over our model objects
    $scope.objects.forEach(function (obj) {
        // loop over all the element positions
        elemPositions.forEach(function (elemId, index) {
            // shave off the string part of the ID on the element.
            var id = parseInt(elemId.replace(/elem-/, ''));

            // Items in the elemPositions array are in the order that they
            // are on the page. If the element ID matches the ID we gave to
            // our object, update the sort order to match the current index.
            if (id === obj.id) {
                obj.sortOrder = index;
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Once we have that setup there's one final thing we need to do. The `stop` event from the jquery sortable widget is executed *outside* of the angular execution block. In other words, angular has no way to know exactly *if* or *when* the sortable is going to update its `objects` array on our `$scope`. Because of this, your view will appear to not update when you sort; though if you iterate over your array you would see the array did indeed update.

We need to force angular to be aware that changes are about to happen to objects in scope. To do this we'll call `scope.$apply` in our directive.

```
return function (scope, element, attributes) {
    element.sortable({
        stop: function(event, ui){
            // Without this, angular magic won't happen when the objects array is updated.
            scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.syncOrder(element.sortable('toArray'));
            });
        }
    });
};
```

### [Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/25gYxygW61hTBSaBRcqF?p=preview)